# Issue using struct in for-loop

Tags: c, pointers, for-loop, struct

This is a homework question. My compiler is CodeBlocks.

Here is my code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Address{
    char number[5];
    char street[30];
    char city[30];
};

struct Employee{
    char ID[7];
    char name[31];
    struct Address *addr;
};

int main(){
    int n,i;
    char temp[7];
    printf("Enter number of Employee : ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    struct Employee **p=(struct Employee **)malloc(n*sizeof(struct Employee *));

    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        p[i]=(struct Employee *)malloc(sizeof(struct Employee));
        p[i]->addr=(struct Address *)malloc(sizeof(struct Address));
    }

    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        printf("Employee #%d\n",i+1);
        printf("Enter ID : ");
        gets(p[i]->ID);
        printf("Enter Name : ");
        gets(p[i]->name);
        printf("Enter Home number : ");
        gets(p[i]->addr->number);
        printf("Enter Street : ");
        gets(p[i]->addr->street);
        printf("Enter City : ");
        gets(p[i]->addr->city);
    }
}
```

My problem is that when I run this code, I cannot enter the ID for the #1 employee; however, I can enter in the ID for employee #2 and #3.

Where is my problem?

Comment: Because `scanf` leaves a newline behind. Also never use `gets` and your code is terrible (no offense, but all those (very small!) fixed size buffers with no checking...)

Comment: I second this. Consider reading about [`getline`](http://www.crasseux.com/books/ctutorial/getline.html#getline), and use `strncpy` to copy the first `n` characters of line into your structure fields.

Comment: Also there is no need to cast the return of `malloc`.

Comment: Shouldn't you be solving your homework yourself?

Comment: @Shahbaz: We allow people to submit problems that they are having with their homework as long as they have put a good-faith effort into solving it themselves and provide their code, asking what the problem is.  We do not allow people to just post their questions and ask for an answer.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be some issue with gets() reading something from the console before the first pass of the loop.

Adding `gets(temp);` right before the loop seems to fix it.  A better solution would be to use something other than gets().

Comment: Meh, if we're just going for quick fixes I prefer `scanf("%d[\n]",&n);`

Comment: Yeah, this code is so awful I couldn't bring myself to do anything but a quick hack.  :-)  It's up to the instructor to grade the overall result once he has it working.

Answer (score 0):

The initial `scanf("%d", &n);` doesn't consume the trailing newline, so it's left available for the `gets()` call.

Incidentally, *never* use `gets()`.  It cannot be used safely.  For example, if you're reading into a 6-byte array, and the user enters 10 characters, you have a buffer overflow.  Consider using `fgets()` instead (but note that, unlike `gets()`, it leaves the `'\n'` character in the buffer).

Comment: fgets leaves also the '\n' in buffer if it's second parameter is to small.

Comment: @user411313: By "buffer", I meant the array into which it stores the line.  If the length argument is big enough (or the entered line is short enough), the string will have a `'\n'` at the end of it; if not, only a partial line will be read, which won't include the `'\n'`, which will be left available for the next input operation.  You still need to do some extra work for 100% robustness in the presence of very long input lines, but for a simple exercise like this it's probably ok just to make the target array big enough and ignore the issue.  (It's certainly better than `gets()`.)

Answer (score 0):

You should ever explicit clear the input buffer after any user-input. And you should make your inputs safe with size limiter. And you should use the return value from scanf.

```
scanf("%d",&n);while(getchar()!='\n');
...
scanf("%6[^\n]",p[i]->ID);while(getchar()!='\n');
...
scanf("%30[^\n]",p[i]->name);while(getchar()!='\n');
...
scanf("%4[^\n]",p[i]->addr->number);while(getchar()!='\n');
...
scanf("%29[^\n]",p[i]->addr->street);while(getchar()!='\n');
...
scanf("%29[^\n]",p[i]->addr->city);while(getchar()!='\n');
```